# How to dynamically add item to listview in Monodroid

Tags: listview, exception, xamarin.android

I am writing an Activity where the user must be able to dynamically add items ( a class with a code and a description ) to a listview by clicking a "add info" button (on top of the screen). Initially the listview is empty. I have made a custom view ( RowItem.axml) which will be inflated in the Adapter GetView() call to display relevant information for the specific row. The problem is in the [add info].Click event where I must add the new item in the list:
The code goes like this:

```
    void button_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
      AddNewItemToListView( listview.count);
    }
    void AddNewItemToListView(int count)
    {
       DataItem item = new DataItem();
       item.Code = FindCode(count);
       item.Description = FindDescription(count);

       listview_adapter.Add( item ); // !!  HERE AN EXCEPTION IS THROWN: --> Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
       listAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And here is the definition of the DataItem:

```
public class DataItem
{
  public string Code {get;set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

And here is the definition of my custom adapter:

```
public class MyListAdapter: ArrayAdapter<DataItem>
{
  // override code here (ex: GetView(..) ... )
```

The whole day I have been searching the web for some examples but I have only found in Android Java not Monodroid. In these examples they use the .Add method of the Adapter (and in most cases adapters with simple types such as string or integer).

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong to get this exception. ( The only thing I noticed is that the method Add of the Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter (my ancestor class) is defined as followed:

```
Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter<T>.Add(T @object);
```

What does the use of "@" mean? Is my exception related to this "@"? I have tried

```
 listview_adapter.Add( @item ); // STILL SAME EXCEPTION
```

Please any help toward the right direction will be very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ArrayAdapter, use BaseAdapter. It gives you the freedom of using a nice data structure like a `List<T>` as the internal data store.

What you want to do is implement your `Add(T item)` method on the adapter that calls through to the List's `Add(T item)` and then calls the adapter's `NotifyDataSetChanged()` method. This instructs the adapter's list view to refresh itself.

Check out [this example](http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview/). It's from a while back, but the code works for setting up a list with custom views. You just have to implement the `Add(T item)` something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter<DataItem>
{
    private readonly List<DataItem> _items = new List<DataItem>();

    // Constructor if you need to set up other stuff.

    public void Add(DataItem item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // Overrides for GetItemId, GetView, Count, this[]
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer sir. I will try it let you know how it went

Comment: Hi Cheesebaron. Sorry to answer so late...many projects to catch up. But thank you for your solution. It did work!! Thanks very much.